# How to hide the "Up button" in the top Fragment and show it in other Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-navigation, up-button

In a Bluetooth-related app (with `minSdkVersion="18"`) I have a single **MainActivity.java**, displaying one of the following 3 UI Fragments:

- **MainFragment.java** (the top screen)
- **SettingsFragment.java** (settings screen, entered through menu)
- **ScanningFragment.java** (lists nearby Bluetooth devices)

[image: screenshot]

To display an "Up button" and handle the "Back button" I have the following code in place:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
                          implements BleWrapperUiCallbacks {

    // set in onResume() of each fragment
    private Fragment mActiveFragment = null;

´   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate())
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_root);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.root, fragment, "main")
                .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                break;

            case R.id.action_settings:
                Fragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .replace(R.id.root, fragment, "settings")
                    .commit();
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

This works well, but has a cosmetic problem, that the "Up button" is still displayed when the **MainFragment.java** is being displayed - as you can see on the left side of the above screenshot.

I have tried calling

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

when that fragment is being active, but that only disables the "Up button" - without really hiding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in luck because in API level 18 there is this:

```
getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```

for support library, it is:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```

So now depending upon what fragment you are in, you can change the icon of "up" button.

Also, try this:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

> Set whether home should be displayed as an "up" affordance.

Comment: Do you know, how to hide the caret "<" character?

Comment: The last part. [`setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled%28boolean%29).

Comment: Just a quick tip: if you ever want to change how the `ActionBar` looks, always have a look at `setDisplay*` methods. There is always something there.

Comment: this helped me
      ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

Answer (score 6):

With help of Little Child (thanks!) here my solution using the [FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener.html):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
                          implements OnBackStackChangedListener,
                                    BleWrapperUiCallbacks {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(
            getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0);
    }
```

Comment: Using `MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener` from androidx, `getSupportActionBar()` works too equivalently.

Answer (score 0):

2021 Working Solution:

```
(requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(null)
```